# Start recording when specific (non-English) name is called in SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, microphone, pyaudio, pocketsphinx

I am trying to create a python program that starts to record whenever I say a specific non-English keyword (name or similar) but I fail to do that. Is it even possible to do that with the help of SpeechRecognition? I also provide my code which is sample:

```
def talk():
    input=sr.Recognizer()
    keywords = [("Oktay", 1), ("hey Oktay", 1), ]
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio=input.listen(source)
        data=""
        try:
            data=input.recognize_sphinx(audio, keyword_entries=keywords)
            print("Your question is, " + data)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Sorry")
    return data
```

Since it is not an English word I always get something similar.

Note: The rest will be in English only the keyword is not an English word.